# How to move a selected (highlighted text) to the right/left in Oracle SQL Developer code editor?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to organize a very large code and I woulde like to do this as fast as possible, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to the right...

select the code

hit the TAB key as necessary

shift+tab to bring it back to the left